# What functions can satisfy these conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

If I have an equation:

$    f(x) / x = f(y) / y$

What functions could $f$ be, given that $x,y$ can take any value?

I know that $f(t) = t$ satisfies it, but I'm curious as to whether there is any other function that could possibly satisfy that condition?

Comment: The function $x\mapsto f(x) /x$ ($x\neq 0$) must be constant.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, $f(x) / x = f(y) / y$ for all $x, y$ means $f(t) / t$ is constant (the function value is the same any two values one could choose), so the only possibilities are of the form $f(t) = ct$, where $c$ is a constant independent of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

You are asked to determine $f(x)$ s.t. $\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{f(y)}{y}$ for every $x,y$.

If we define a related function $f_1$ as: $f_1(t)=\frac{f(t)}{t}$, your statement is the same as saying that $f_1(x)=f_1(y)$ for every $x,y$.

This essentially means $f_1$ must be a constant, since it takes the same value everywhere.